# Returning the Heaviest path (with the highest sum of a given property in all of it's relations) from a node to all of its leafs

Tags: python, neo4j, cypher, dijkstra, py2neo

Is there a way to write a Cypher query which returns the path which has the highest sum all of the (selected) relation's property among all of the existing paths from a given node to its leaf children?

Hello,
First i would state how I created the graph:

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (j:JOB) ASSERT j.order_id IS UNIQUE

USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
//EXPLAIN
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///jobs.csv" AS row
MERGE (j:JOB {order_id: row.child_order_id})
SET j.job_name = row.child_job_name,
    j.job_owner = row.child_job_owner,
    j.group_name = row.child_group_name,
    j.order_time = row.child_order_time,
    j.start_time = row.child_start_time,
    j.end_time = row.child_end_time;

USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///child_father.csv" AS row
MATCH (c:JOB {order_id: row.child_order_id})
MATCH (f:JOB {order_id: row.father_order_id})
MERGE (c)-[d:DEPENDS_ON]->(f)
SET d.elapsed_min = row.elapsed_min;
```

Now, my goal is to return the path with the highest sum of the relations property 'elapsed_min' from a given order id, to all of the leaf nodes it depends on.

since i couldn't find a way to do so in Cypher, I tried on python using py2neo library.
At first i tried using a normal Dijksta algorithm to return the lightest path and after i can do that i would alter the algorithm to return the heaviest path

so i made this:

```
import py2neo
from py2neo import Graph
from py2neo import Node, Relationship

NEO4J_URI = "bolt://127.0.0.1:7687"
NEO4J_USER = "neo4j"
NEO4J_PASSWORD = "neo4j"

graph = Graph(NEO4J_URI, auth = (NEO4J_USER, NEO4J_PASSWORD), bolt = True)

def dijkstra(graph,start,goal):
    shortest_distance = {}
    predecessor = {}
    unseenNodes = graph
    infinity = 999999
    path = []

    for node in unseenNodes:
        shortest_distance[node] = infinity
    shortest_distance[start] = 0

    while unseenNodes:
        minNode = None
        for node in unseenNodes:
            if minNode is None:
                minNode = node
            elif shortest_distance[node] < shortest_distance[minNode]:
                minNode = node

        for childNode, weight in graph[minNode].items():
            if weight + shortest_distance[minNode] < shortest_distance[childNode]:
                shortest_distance[childNode] = weight + shortest_distance[minNode]
                predecessor[childNode] = minNode

        unseenNodes.pop(minNode)

    # get the path
    currentNode = goal
    while currentNode != start:
        try:
            path.insert(0,currentNode)
            currentNode = predecessor[currentNode]
        except KeyError:
            print("Path not reachable")
            break

    if shortest_distance[goal] != infinity:
        print('Shortest distance is: ' + str(shortest_distance[goal]))
        print('And the path is: ' + str(path))
```

now i need to find a way to return the paths in this json format so i could run the Dijkstra algorithm on it, like this:

```
testGraph = {'a':{'b':10,'c':3},'b':{'c':1,'d':2},'c':{'b':4,'d':8,'e':2},'d':{'e':7},'e':{'d':9}}
#the relation property that means the distance from node: a to b is 10, a to c is 3, b to c is 1 and so on...

dijkstra(testGraph, 'a', 'd')

#the output is: Shortest distance is: 9
#               And the path is: ['c', 'b', 'd']
```

But I am not sure how to return the right path and which format will fit best..
this is what I've got and i cant send this to my algorithm:

```
testGraph = graph.run(   "MATCH (c:JOB)-[d:DEPENDS_ON*]->(f:JOB) "
                    "WHERE c.order_id = '4p0ta' "
                    "RETURN * "
                    "LIMIT 50").to_table()#data() #to_subgraph #to_data_frame()
```

Answer (score 0):

This Cypher query should return the path (ending at a leaf node) with the highest sum:

```
MATCH p=(c:JOB)-[:DEPENDS_ON*]->(f:JOB)
WHERE c.order_id = '4p0ta' AND NOT (f)-[:DEPENDS_ON]->()
RETURN p, REDUCE(s = 0, d IN RELATIONSHIPS(p) | s + d.elapsed_min) AS total
ORDER BY total DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Note that [variable-length relationships](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/clauses/match/#varlength-rels) can be very expensive (i.e., take a very long time or even run out of memory) if your paths are long and/or your nodes have a lot of relationships. You may need to set an upper bound on the length to be able to use this query.

Comment: thanks, it did help a lot.
How does this query handle dependency loops within a path?

Comment: You can also check the maximum spanning tree algorithm in neo4j graph algorithma